# get name of table in function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need get name of table inside function:

```
SELECT f(name) FROM table;
```

how can i get table’s name (*table*) in function f?

Comment: *Which* table?  I don't understand what you want.

Comment: table, where i use function f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get that implicitly, because there are no ties between the table in the `FROM` clause and the values fed to the function.

Imagine a query like

```
SELECT f(a.col1 + b.col2)
FROM a CROSS JOIN b;
```

There is no single table involved!

If you need to pass a table to a function, you have to explicitly pass it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(p_name text, p_table regclass) RETURNS ...
AS ...
```

You could call that like

```
SELECT f(name, a.tableoid) FROM atable AS a;
```

Comment: You can avoid the hardcoded name in the string using `SELECT f(name, tableoid::regclass) FROM atable`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good idea. The cast is implicit.